# Python & Matplotlib - Creating date ticks from string

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib, plot

I have an array of strings which contain dates formatted as such: '01/01/09'. I also have an array of floats with the date values.

I want to take these dates and ultimately display them as x tick labels on my graph.

How do I use the floats or strings to label the ticks on the x-axis on my matplotlib graph? (using something like xticks)

Answer (score 7):

You set the count (and values) of the ticks using `set_xticks`.  You set the text of the ticks using `set_xticklabels`

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3],[3,4,3])
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xticks([1,2,3])
ax.set_xticklabels(['1/1','1/2','1/3'])
```